# Python Session Dependent Task Queue?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, session, celery

I have 1000 objects in my system, each having a particular http session.

At random intervals, each object generates a task and add it to it's own queue, where they will need to send a http request somewhere.

I thought of solving this through a simple Task Queue, but the tasks are not independent, they must follow a certain order.
Plus, for each session, only 1 task might be executing at a certain time, and every one of it's tasks must follow a certain interval.

I basically need 1 master, N slaves, where each slave has session and a task queue of all tasks related to it's session.

What is the correct pattern for this problem?
What modules should I be using to solve this?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem, what have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I like to find the best solution before putting my hands to work.

Comment: I think I'll go for a Client/Server architecture, connected by a Redis queue, which will send the sessions to the clients, and send the requests to the clients when they are generated.